# Finding covergence/divergence of series using the integral test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the series:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1+{1 \over n})^n$

And I need to find if it converges or diverges using the integral test. I think that the sequence of

$(1+{1 \over n})^n$

Will converge to $e^1$ = $e$.

Does that mean that the original series will converge to $e$ as well, or will I have to take the definite integral from 1 to $\infty$ and then the limit of that?

Comment: The integral test will not tell you anything about the value of your series; other than if it is successful you will not its something finite

Comment: A very important question would be if $a_n\geq 1$ then is it possible that $\sum a_n$ is convergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It diverges [because](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) the term $(1+1/n)^n$ does not goes to zero. In fact: $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e.$$

Comment: Thank you I completely forgot about that!